# How to restrict the debug mode to a specific domain in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, environment-variables, contao

In order to set your app or website in debug mode you can define the following variable in your .env file in Symfony:

```
APP_ENV=dev
# Is it possible to define a domain rule?
```

Is it possible to define a domain rule? If you have a multi domain web project it would be very helpful to restrict the debug mode to a specific domain.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged this question with `contao`, I assume you are running the Contao Managed Edition? If yes, you can enable the debug mode via a button in the top right in the back end (when logged in as an administrator). You can also enable the debug mode via the Contao Manager under *Maintenance*. Either of these options will enable the debug mode only *for you* (via a Cookie).

Comment: Perfect! Yes - only for me and only for one domain! Contao rocks!!!